# How to compare hash tables in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, compare, hashtable

I want to compare 2 hash tables in sql server 2008 using query. Whether its possible or not

Please Help

Comment: Give us more information please: structure, sample data, desired output etc

Comment: ...the same way you'd compare any 2 tables?